# validation rule apply for phone and mobile both in single validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

```
AND(NOT(REGEX(Phone,'\\d*')), NOT(REGEX(Phone,'\(\\d{3}\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}')))
```

I have applied validation rule for phone now requirement is there is another field which is mobile (standard field of contact object) is also mention in this same rule how can i mention for mobile also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition with OR operator.

```
OR(
   AND(NOT(REGEX(Phone,'^\\d*$')), NOT(REGEX(Phone,'^[(]\\d{3}[)][ ]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}$'))),
   AND(NOT(REGEX(MobilePhone,'^\\d*$')), NOT(REGEX(MobilePhone,'^[(]\\d{3}[)][ ]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}$')))
)
```

`^\\d*$` = Input is Number only

`^[(]\\d{3}[)][ ]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}$` = Takes input in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.

Comment: its showing syntax error i'm not be able to detact

Comment: I have updated the Regex in my answer.